# ORA-00917, missing comma

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and am in the process of taking an intro to DBMS class. We are inserting things into our table and I cannot for the life of me find where Im missing a comma.
The professor of this class has done little to no actual teaching and just refers us to youtube so we're on our own. If anyone can point me in the right direction... that would be awesome.
It is worth noting we are writing our sql code into the Apex Oracle website as well.

````
INSERT INTO PROJECTDATA (ProjectID,ProjectName,ProjDeptID,MaxHours,StartDate,EndDate)
VALUES
(901,'Product Plan',3001,135,TO_DATE(10-May-12,'DD-Mon-YYYY'), TO_DATE(15-Sep-12,'DD-Mon-YYYY');

INSERT INTO PROJECTDATA (ProjectID,ProjectName,ProjDeptID,MaxHours,StartDate,EndDate)
VALUES
(902,'Tax Preparation',1001,120,TO_DATE('05/Jul/12','DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_DATE('15/Oct/12','DD-MON-YYYY')```
````

Comment: What **version** of Oracle Server are you using?

Comment: You really should add some whitespace to your SQL query so that it's readable. SQL is not sensitive to whitespace and you can format your INSERT statement component-parts to be more readable.

Comment: I will definitely take into consideration the white space. Im not even doing any formatting yet and more just trying to make sure I get the code itself right.

Comment: As far as what version.. I believe it is just whatever is the most up to date? we log into the apex.oracle.com website and it doesn't prompt us for a version number

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are missing the closing brackets in your query.

Try

```
INSERT INTO PROJECTDATA (ProjectID,ProjectName,ProjDeptID,MaxHours,StartDate,EndDate)
VALUES (901,'Product Plan',3001,135,TO_DATE(10-May-12,'DD-Mon-YYYY'), TO_DATE(15-Sep-12,'DD-Mon-YYYY'));
```

Note the extra closing bracket at the end of statement - you only had one which closed the `TO_DATE` statement. Without the closing bracket it considered the following statement part of the first query - causing it to give you misleading comma errors

Comment: holy cow Im an idiot. Ive been staring at this for so long and was just getting so frustrated.

Comment: So correcting that fixed the 2nd set of data but now the first is throwing a "column not allowed here" error

Comment: scratch that. I fixed it. The date formatting given to us in the assignment itself is incorrect. Minor tweak and i got it!
Thank you for pointing out the obvious!

Comment: I'm sure this is not a working query at all, because `10-may-12` without quotes is not a valid SQL expression

Comment: @VeritasCurat . . . This code simply doesn't run.  Why is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

`to_date()` accepts a string argument, so the date literals should be enclosed in single quotes, e.g.

```
TO_DATE('10-May-12','DD-Mon-YYYY')
        ^
        | here
```